# Why is Entity Framework Core generating a LEFT JOIN?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, inner-join

I am trying to generate a one to many query using `INNER JOIN` just as I would normally in SQL. I've simplified the model and the query to easier explain the problem.

I have defined this relationship as a one to many that is a required relationship, but even with this simple statement I can't get it to generate an `INNER JOIN`. I don't want the `LEFT JOIN` here or the `ORDER BY` clause which for some reason EF has added. Can someone please help?

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Author>()
    .HasKey(x => x.Id);

modelBuilder.Entity<Author>()
    .HasMany(x => x.Books)            
    .WithOne(x => x.Author)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.AuthorId)
    .IsRequired();

modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
    .HasKey(x => x.Id);

modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
    .HasOne(x => x.Author)
    .WithMany(x => x.Books)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.AuthorId)
    .IsRequired();
```

```cs
public class Author
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
var results = Context.Authors.Include(x => x.Books).ToList();
```

This will then generate the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT [f].[Id], [f].[Name], [f0].[Id], [f0].[Name]
FROM [Author] AS [f]
LEFT JOIN [Book] AS [f0] ON [f].[Id] = [f0].[AuthorId]
ORDER BY [f].[Id], [f0].[Id]
```

Why is Entity Framework adding an `ORDER BY` clause when I didn't specify it? And why is it generating a `LEFT JOIN` when my relationships are specified as required in the fluent API configuration?

Comment: Left join is correct because you are asking for a list of authors. Inner join would hide authors that don't have books yet. The order by is for EF to be able to sort the rows into objects, so that it knows when the id changes, a new object has to be created, and that the previous object does not need to be tracked anymore.

Comment: Because you are trying to get all `Author`s and then include their books. If there is a author, that doesn't have any book, it wouldn't be included when using simple `join`, thus `left join` to assure you will get all authors, independently of having a book.
With ordering, I am not really sure, but I think that is default EF mechanism, which sorts results by their IDs

Comment: OrderBy: because that makes it a lot easier to materialize the objects and includes - they are all where they belong (i.e. once an author is done with all books, you never go back to it).

Comment: Why do you expect or not expect anything in particular? What has your research shown, including the documentation? If you don't tell us both what you expect & why then we can't address your misconceptions or what you understand correctly & you are just asking us to rewrite the documentation & SO answers.